# Can't use underlying type of string inside map of string: "cannot use <xxx> (type <yyy>) as type string in map index"

Tags: string, go

I have underlying type of string: `type Capability string`.

I wanted to use it as a string inside map of strings but I am getting an error:

> cannot use cap (type Capability) as type string in map index

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


type Capability string
var caps_list = map[string]int {
    "HOME" : 1,
}

func main() {

    var cap Capability // string
    cap = "HOME"
    fmt.Print(string(caps_list[cap]))
}
```

Why it doesn't accept it ? it is a string after all.

You can try my code here:
https://play.golang.org/p/r-h9Hu8_eoM

Comment: Your map has keys of type `string`, so you must use `string` and not `Capability`. Which is easy as you can convert a Capability to a string.

Comment: @Volker how do I conver? with `strconv` ?  didn't see an option to do it.

Comment: I also tried string(cap) but I am getting other errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to change to use `string` on the cap:

```
fmt.Print(string(caps_list[string(cap)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a string. It is a type, wich base type is a string.

So the exact type is important. You can also not add celcius to fahrenheit degrees, even if both types would have integer base types.